# Unable to create stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sequelpro

I have created a stored procedure as follow :

```
create procedure load_data()
BEGIN
DECLARE vcounter INT DEFAULT 0;
while vcounter < 1000 do
    if vcounter % 2<>0 then 
        INSERT INTO EMPDetails ( id, name ) VALUES ( null, 'Adrian','Test','1989-07-09',vcounter);
    else 
        INSERT INTO EMPDetails ( id, name ) VALUES ( null, 'Jimmy','Bank','1989-07-06',vcounter);
    set vcounter=vcounter+1;
end while;
END
```

I executed it in sequel pro but it always says this

```
[ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
Execution stopped!
```

I checked my procedure and it seems in order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your **[`if-else`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)** with `END IF`.

```
if vcounter % 2<>0 then 
        INSERT INTO EMPDetails ( id, name ) VALUES ( null, 'Adrian','Test','1989-07-09',vcounter);
    else 
        INSERT INTO EMPDetails ( id, name ) VALUES ( null, 'Jimmy','Bank','1989-07-06',vcounter);
    set vcounter=vcounter+1;
end if;
```

Also, list of columns in `INSERT` ***MUST*** match with the values specified.